# Does oninput work in Chrome for radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Does anybody know if the `oninput` tag works in Chrome for radio buttons? Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Weirdness</title></head>
<body>
    <input type="number" min="1" size="2" oninput="window.alert(this.value);">
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="A" oninput="window.alert(this.value);">
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="B" oninput="window.alert(this.value);">
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this in Firefox, the `window.alert()` calls work perfectly fine when I change one of the inputs. But when I run this on Chrome, the radio button doesn't call the function when I select a radio button. This, despite all the specs I've found that say that Chrome supports `oninput`. Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: workaround: use onchange for radio buttons

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda--that's exactly the workaround that I'm using. This seems like it might be a full Chrome bug, though--either that or a very weird "feature".

Comment: The "`oninput`" event is similar to the "`onkeypress`", "`onkeyup`" and "`onkeydown`" events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) when in doubt.

```
Feature        Chrome   Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari 
Basic support  (Yes)    2               9                   10      (Yes)
```

However, according to the [Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input), the event is...

> Fired at controls when the user changes the value (see also the change
>   event)

Since clicking a button or checkbox or radio button doesn't actually change it's value, it technically probably shouldn't be triggered or relied upon to trigger on a radio button.

I can confirm it does not work in Chrome 48.

Comment: But, surprisingly it does not work in Chrome, atleast in version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit).

Comment: That might have to do with the specs - seems `oninput` is only supposed to work for text-inputs (number, search, text, and so on). So it might be that Chrome has a slightly stricter implementation?

Comment: you could argue that it is firefox that has the bug - though, the specification does not restrict `input` events to textual type input controls - so, the spec is ambiguous enough to cause these inconsitencies

Comment: Yeah--that seems to be the case. It looks like I fell prey to some very misleading docs...`onchange` and `oninput` actually differ quite a bit: not just in when they trigger, but why they trigger. (At least in Chrome.)