# How to call the function as soon as the text changes in input box in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in vue I am writing a form, input box when text changes it updates the function `setMessage`

```
<input type="text" v-model="test" v-on:change"setMessage">
```

but the problem is it only updates if I click somewhere outside the input box.

I believe their might be something other than `change` event !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fire an event when v-model changes ? (vue js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257379/how-to-fire-an-event-when-v-model-changes-vue-js)

Comment: The question linked above is not the same thing, that question is about receiving an event too soon due to using onclick rather than onchange - totally different?

Comment: @Durga not a duplicate. I can see no relation between this question and the linked one.

Comment: @bbsimonbb check all the answers of that question, all related to input element, that's why closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Durga, yup, but the other question is about a radio and this is about a text input. In text, you want to listen to `oninput`. On a radio, oninput [isn't even available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900097/1585345).

Comment: Ciasto, are you sure? Your v-model is already updating `test` whenever the value changes. Why do you want to also call a function? If you can get away with just using v-model, you should. Avoid listener style code if you can. Can this be done with reactivity? `watch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead:

```
<input type="text" v-model="test" v-on:input="setMessage">
```